# Youtube not playing, Adobe flash installed! Dailymotion and other videos sides work good!

Tags: 12.04, youtube

As my title says, dailymotion and other video sites work good, But youtube does play videos please help.

Ubuntu 12.04 version, 32 Bit operating system.

Comment: You should include more info... What browser? Did you install ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Comment: I have tried chromium n firefox as well! :(

Comment: Do you, perhaps,live in the country that blocks youtube?

Comment: In windows its works perfectly. !

Comment: If I understood well, you already tried running the flashplugin-installer again? What happens if you run minitube (install first: sudo apt-get install minitube)? This little program plays (and downloads) youtube-videos in a seperate window. Would be interesting to know if this works. Good luck